# SSIS connection string based on a variable

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

This is a follow up to my question: [SSIS connection parameter based on parameter/variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35181719/ssis-connection-parameter-based-on-parameter-variable)

I now can see how to construct a variable from other variables, but it does not appear possible to then use that variable as the ConnectionString for the Connection.  That appears to only allow variables.

How can I use my newly concatenated variable as the ConnectionString?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I can answer my own question now.  It is a different location than if you want to use a parameter to set the ConnectionString.

Click on the Connection in Connect Manager and in the Properties window, expand Expressions.  There you can click the ... to set it to a variable.